# Show tensor $g_{ij}A^iB^j $ is invariant under coordinate change

Tags: differential-geometry, tensors, index-notation

The components of a $(0,2)$ tensor is $(g_{ij})$ and the components of a $(1,0)$ tensor is $A^i,B^j$.

How can I show that the quantity (using Einstein summation convention)

$$g_{ij}A^iB^j $$ 
is invariant? 
So I want to show that the value does not change when coordinate systems are changed.

One hint that the textbook gives me is to use the Kronecker delta, so I know that is:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n \frac{\partial\bar{x}^i}{\partial x^j}\frac{\partial x^k}{\partial\bar{x}^i} = \delta_{j}^k$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to show that if the coordinate transform as $x^i \rightarrow \bar{x}^{\mu}$, then
$$ \bar{g}_{\mu\nu} \bar{A}^{\mu}\bar{B}^{\nu} = g_{ij} A^{i} B^{j} $$
You can show this by first note that the components of the tensors in this new coordinate system is (by the transformation rule for tensor components)
$$ \bar{g}_{\mu\nu} = g_{ij} \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial \bar{x}^{\mu} } \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial \bar{x}^{\nu} }$$
$$
\bar{A}^{\mu} =A^{k}  \frac{\partial \bar{x}^{\mu} }{\partial x^k} \qquad 
\bar{B}^{\nu} =B^{l}  \frac{\partial \bar{x}^{\nu} }{\partial x^l} 
$$
And after substitution to $ \bar{g}_{\mu\nu} \bar{A}^{\mu}\bar{B}^{\nu} $ you can use your hint above to show that it is equal to $g_{ij} A^{i} B^{j}$.

Comment: Thank you! When you say substitute, do you mean $\bar{g}_{\mu v}\bar{A}^\mu\bar{B}^v = A^k \frac{\partial\bar{x}^\mu}{\partial x^k}B^l\frac{\partial\bar{x}^v}{\partial x^l}$?

Comment: Yeah. But you forgot your $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu}$.

Answer (score 3):

Here is an index-free solution. Represent $G=(g_{ij})$ as a matrix, $a=(A^i)$ and $b=(B^j)$ as vectors. Then $g_{ij}A^iB^j$ can be written as $a^\top Gb$. We change the coordinate system via a transformation $T$. This yields:

$$a\mapsto Ta,\qquad b\mapsto Tb,\qquad G\mapsto (T^{-1})^\top GT^{-1}.$$

We then have

$$a^\top Gb
\quad\mapsto\quad 
(T a)^\top (T^{-1})^\top GT^{-1} (T b) 
=  a^\top \underbrace{T^\top (T^{-1})^\top}_IG\underbrace{T^{-1} T}_I b
= a^\top G b.
$$

You can try writing this out with indices if necessary.

Comment: I think the expression for the transf of $G$ should involve $T^{-1}$ ? Because (by looking at its entries) it is the inverse of jacobian matrix $T$.

Comment: @Sou I changed it. But I assume $T^\top=T^{-1}$ later anyway because the result does not old for other transformations.

Comment: No i mean because $\bar{g}_{\mu\nu} = g_{ij} \frac{\partial x^i}{\partial \bar{x}^{\mu} } \frac{\partial x^j}{\partial \bar{x}^{\nu} }$, then the matrix that multiplied by $G$ should both in form $T^{-1}$, if you choose to represent $\frac{\partial \bar{x}^{\mu} }{\partial x^i}$ by $T$. So it (maybe) must be $T^{-1}G(T^{-1})^T$ ?

Comment: @Sou Good point. If I am not mistaken, then this is still the same as your answer: $$(TGT^{-1})_{jl}=T_{ij}G_{jk}(T^{-1})_{kl}=G_{jk}T_{ij}(T^{-1})_{kl}=G_{jk}(T^\top)_{ji}(T^{-1})_{kl}=G_{jk}(T^{-1})_{ji}(T^{-1})_{kl}.$$
I do not pay attention to upper and lower indices here.

Comment: Probably. But what make me feel uncomfortable here is that the assumption of orthogonality $TT^T=I$ here. I think it should be hold for any transformation

Comment: Maybe this $a^T T^T . (T^{-1})^T G T^{-1} . Tb$ ?

Comment: @Sou Thought about it too. I will use this. I am not sooo familiar with index notation, so thatnk you for your help.